# Agrupar arrays en primeras posiciones

Tags: java, array

Si yo tengo por ejemplo un array con 10 posiciones y tengo asignados numeros o lo que sea en algunas posiciones,

de que forma podes agrupar lo que tengas asignado a esas posiciones para que te queden todas en el principio y las posiciones nulas dejarlas al final?

```
public void agrupaSurtidores(){
        for(int i = 0; i<cantPosiciones();i++){
            if(tabla[i] == null){
              boolean agrupe = false
                for(int j = i+1; j<cantPosiciones() && !agrupe ;j++){
                    if(tabla[j] != null){
                        tabla[i] = tabla[j];
                        tabla[j] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

lo que pense fue que si una posicion es nula, a partir de ahi busco la primera posicion no nula y lo asigno

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: esa... de que forma podes agrupar lo que tengas asignado a esas posiciones para que te queden todas en el principio y las posiciones nulas dejarlas al final?

Comment: te recomiendo pasar todo lo de tu arreglo a uno nuevo que funcione como heap, es decir un arreglo que reresente un arbol binario, asi puedes agrupar no solamente separando los nulos, sino tambien ordenando los numeros

Comment: si no necesitas ordenar puedes usar un arreglo como pila y meterle los numeros mediante copia uno a uno saltandote los nulos hasta llegar a las dimensiones del arreglo

Comment: claro, osea creo otro arreglo y paso todo ahi en las primeras posiciones directamente... a mi se me habia ocurrido una forma de hacerlo pero nose si está bien y es eficiente, ahora lo edito y lo pongo en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Podrias filtrar los elementos diferentes de `null` y los `iguales`,al mismo tiempo los guardas en un respectivo array  por separado,luego usas el mismo array original para unir los dos obtenidos usando [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-javfirst.lang.Object-int-javfirst.lang.Object-int-int-)

ejemplo

```
Integer [] numeros={2,3,4,5,null,4,3,null};

Integer[]a=Arrays.stream(numeros).filter(c->c!=null).toArray(Integer[]::new);
Integer[]b=Arrays.stream(numeros).filter(c->c==null).toArray(Integer[]::new);

System.arraycopy(a, 0, numeros, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, numeros, a.length, b.length);


System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]